# Most Recent by category

Tags: t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I have a table with the following records:

```
Create table MemberCount 
(
    ssn char(9) null,
    extract_begin_dt smalldatetime null,
    extract_end_dt   smalldatetime null,
    memberCase varchar(13) null
)

insert into MemberCount(ssn, extract_begin_dt, extract_end_dt, memberCase) 
values (1, '1/1/2017', '1/31/2017', 'Non-Funded'),
       (1, '2/1/2017', '12/31/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (2, '1/1/2017', '3/31/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (2, '4/1/2017', '12/31/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (3, '1/1/2014', '3/31/2014', 'OpenAccts'),
       (3, '4/1/2014', '10/31/2017', 'ClosedAccts'),
       (3, '11/1/2017', '12/31/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '9/19/2017', '12/31/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '9/15/2017', '9/18/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '8/26/2017', '9/14/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '4/9/2015', '8/25/2017', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '4/8/2015', '4/8/2015', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '4/7/2015', '4/7/2015', 'ClosedAccts'),
       (7, '1/1/2015', '4/6/2015', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '5/22/2014', '12/31/2014', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '8/21/2013', '5/21/2014', 'OpenAccts'),
       (7, '6/20/2013', '8/20/2013', 'Non-Funded'),
       (7, '4/20/2013', '6/19/2013', 'Non-Funded'),
       (7, '1/12/2011', '1/12/2011', 'DeletedAccts'),
       (7, '12/31/2010', '1/11/2011', 'OpenAccts')
```

The expected result

```
ssn   begin_dt
----------------
1     2/1/2017
2     1/1/2017
3     11/1/2017
7     12/31/2017
```

The rules are if there is no memberCase other then OpenAccount the min date will be chosen, if there other then OpenAccount it will go until the open account will be the current one

I've tried with windows function but number 2 and 3 are opposite logic

Thanks,

Oded Dror

Comment: You can simplify your `INSERT` by using comma-separated `VALUES` clauses, you don't need to repeat the `INSERT INTO` part.

Comment: `if there other then OpenAccount it will go until the open account will be the current one` <-- what does this mean?  Please elaborate on the second rule.

Comment: Open Account is the diver for determination of member since date
So ssn 1 1/1/17 is non founded so the current one will be 2/1/2017
ssn 2 if there no MeberCase other then Open account the minimum will be chosen 1/1/17
ssn if member case other then open account so the most recent will be chose 11/1/17 same for ssn 7 12/31/17 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this query. But result is a bit different from your provided result. For `ssn=7` you expect `12/31/2017`. But it is `extract_end_dt`. Are not you getting `extract_begin_dt`?

```
select
    ssn, extract_begin_dt
from (
    select 
        *, mc1 = min(memberCase) over (partition by ssn), mc2 = max(memberCase) over (partition by ssn)
        , dt1 = min(extract_begin_dt) over (partition by ssn), dt2 = max(extract_begin_dt) over (partition by ssn)
    from 
        MemberCount
) t
where
    1 = case
        when mc1 = mc2 and mc1 = 'OpenAccts' and dt1 = extract_begin_dt then 1
        when mc1 <> mc2 and dt2 = extract_begin_dt then 1
        else 0
    end
```

Result

```
ssn        extract_begin_dt
1          2017-02-01 00:00:00
2          2017-01-01 00:00:00
3          2017-11-01 00:00:00
7          2017-09-19 00:00:00
```

Edit: updated query according to your comment

```
select
    ssn, begin_dt = max(begin_dt)
from (
    select
        ssn, grp, begin_dt = min(extract_begin_dt) 
    from (
        select
            *, grp = rn - row_number() over (partition by ssn order by extract_begin_dt)
        from (
            select
                *, rn = row_number() over (partition by ssn order by extract_begin_dt)
            from
                MemberCount
        ) t
        where
            memberCase = 'OpenAccts'
    ) t
    group by ssn, grp
) t
group by ssn
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I did not sort it by extract_begin-dt 
But if you sort it you will see that 4/8/2015 is the first one with OpenAccts after the 4/7/2015 ClosedAccts so 4/8/2017 should be the correct one.

Comment: Uzi,

It Works, 

Thanks